# SQLAlchemy: Can't join m2m

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two models called Items and Privileges. There is a relationship defined between them with a m2m table:

```
class Privilege(Archiveable):
    __tablename__ = 'privileges'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    items = relationship('Item', secondary='privileges_have_items', back_populates='privileges', lazy='raise')
    ....

class Item(Archiveable):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    privileges = relationship('Privilege', secondary='privileges_have_items', back_populates='items', lazy='raise')
    ....
```

I am trying to join the two tables like so (entity type = Item class):

```
allowed_entities_query = select(entity_type).options(join(entity_type, Privilege))
```

But I still get:
`sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'items' and 'privileges'.` Though they are clearly defined above. Do I need to define an on clause? That seems weird since I already defined their relationship.
A joinedload does work, but I want to only join if: `.where(Privilege.id.in_(filtered_privileges_ids))` and I read I then need to do a `.join` with a `.filter`
How can I achieve this?

Any help is appreciated as the documentation seems to be either very lacking or very hard to find (note that I am using the new API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using `options` construct. I think the query should work simply using the `join` on the `select` statement:

```
allowed_entities_query = select(entity_type).join(entity_type.privileges)
```

, or more explicitely:

```
allowed_entities_query = select(entity_type).join(Privileges, entity_type.privileges)
```

*And [Joins](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/queryguide.html#joins) are very well documented.*

Comment: I see. When I saw 1.4 and 'query' I assumed it was regarding the old query method (I still don't understand why the docs are not called 2.0, I'm new to sqlalchemy). As for .options, that is how I used joinedload so it made sense for me to use it for .join also. Then it was asking for a right side of the join as well which confused me even more. Thanks!